# Mesh Problems with MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix, bugs, mesh

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.0 or later**

---

I've come across some weird behavior in 10.1 when trying to use Mesh with MatrixPlot. In the example below, when specifying Mesh, I only get one line along the X axis at 100 instead of lines at {100, 200, ..., 500}.  I assume this is a bug, but does anyone know of a work around.

Thanks,

Mike

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 500}];

MatrixPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Full,
 FrameTicks -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - #] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
 MeshStyle -> Blue,
 Mesh -> { Table[j, {j, 0, 25, 5}], Table[j, {j, 100, 500, 100}] }
 ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution or rather "fix" to the problem seems to be to raise the `MaxPlotPoints`:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 500}];

MatrixPlot[
    data,
    AspectRatio -> Full, 
    FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - #] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
    MeshStyle -> Blue, 
    Mesh -> {Table[j, {j, 0, 25, 5}], Table[j, {j, 100, 500, 100}]}, 
    MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity
]
```

This returns:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This started out as a long comment, but in the meantime I think I found the solution to this problem which is clearly a bug in `MatrixPlot`. My initial analysis follows and the conclusion **and a solution** are at the bottom.

First, this is not typical to 10.1. I see identical behavior in versions 8 and 9.

Second, your example can be simplified to reduce the phenomenon to its essentials:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {20, 500}];
MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {{5, 10, 15}, {100, 200, 300}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference in data ranges plays a role. Increasing the vertical range of the matrix adds the missing grid lines:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {200, 500}];
MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {{5, 10, 15}, {100, 200, 300}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another problem when we let Mathematica choose the mesh *locations*:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {20, 500}];
MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {4, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again, with less of a difference in data ranges:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {200, 500}];
MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {4, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Looks like a bug to me.**

Note that `ArrayPlot` works correctly with the same options:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {20, 500}];
ArrayPlot[data, Mesh -> {{5, 10, 15}, {100, 200, 300}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {20, 500}];
ArrayPlot[data, Mesh -> {4, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Drilling down further

Let's look at the underlying Graphics code of the resulting plot:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {20, 300}];
mp = MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 20, 3}], Table[i, {i, 0, 300, 10}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mp // InputForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ah! The array is changed into a `SparseArray`, but its horizontal dimension is incorrect. The vertical mesh lines, drawn with `Line`, seem to use coordinates that are derived from this incorrect `SparseArray` dimension.

Let's change the data array somewhat again:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {50, 300}];
mp = MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 50, 3}], Table[i, {i, 0, 300, 10}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mp // InputForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `SparseArray` is correct here, and the mesh lines are correct as well.

The same dimensional error is found when one replaces the `ConstantArray` with a random array. You don't get a `SparseArray` in the Graphics code, but a `Raster` instead. Again, with the incorrect dimensions:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Cause and solution

I suspect the cause of this problem to be an incorrect handling of the downsampling of the input data.

The `MatrixPlot` documentation says:

> With the default setting MaxPlotPoints->Automatic, sufficiently large
>   or sparse matrices are downsampled so that their structure is visible
>   in the plot generated by MatrixPlot.

So, prohibiting this downsampling could be a solution. Let's try this:

```
data = ConstantArray[0, {20, 500}];
MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> {{5, 10, 15}, {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}}, 
 MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Seems to work. Graphics will be much more memory intensive though. I noted that this subsampling is doing pretty weird things. A 20 x 500 matrix will be subsampled, but a 50 x 500 won't.

Comment: +1. That is of course a very concise explanation of what is going on behind the scenes. Great.